# Asp.Net System.Web.Routing won't route URL unless .aspx in on the end

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have a weird problem with routing.  I have an existing website that I am trying to add this to.  It works, but only if .aspx is on the end of the URL. If I remove the .aspx, it gives me an error: "The resource cannot be found."  I created a quick test website and copied the code over to it, it works just fine.  The code between the 2 are identical.  Both are running on the VS 2008 web server.  I just don't get it.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: what version of IIS? And if 7 what pipeline mode are you using?

Comment: I am just using the built-in web server with VS 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. I don't understand why this caused the problem, but if there is a period (.) anywhere in the URL, it errors.

I had this: http://localhost:49463/site.dev/products/keylessentrykits

When I changed it to: http://localhost:49463/sitedev/products/keylessentrykits, removing the period between site and dev, it worked fine.

Anyone have a clue to why this is?  Is it a bug?

Also, I should have said something before, but this is not an MVC app.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a bug.  You should file it -  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the ISAPI dll to handle all files (i.e. add a wildcard).  It's working because it's set to handle .aspx.

Comment: I am only using the built-in web server in VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you kindly for finding the solution and posting it.  I have been suffering from the exact same issue and have been trying to get it resolved for days now!

My solution contains several projects: web, business logic, data access, etc.  My web project was called "SystemName.WebForms" and when I was compiling and running from Visual Studio's debugging environment only routes that contained a period were being routed properly.  Once I renamed my web project to "SystemName_WebForms" all of the routes were processed properly.  I highly suspect this is a bug that you discovered.

Many thanks for finding the workaround and having the generosity to post it!

MomentSurfer